# Open/close a winform application from ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, winforms

Is there a way to open/close (i.e. start-up/shut-down) a winform application via ASP.NET?  I'm sure this reeks of a security violation, but the application of this technique (if it's even possible) would be in a controlled environment.

I assume extra permissions would need to be granted to the web server or the web application, but I'm not sure what the permissions are.

Comment: Can you clarify if you want to launch an application on the users machine or on the server? I read your question as wanting to launch an application that is running on the server, but it seems the responses so far are talking about running applications on the client.

Comment: Good question.  I want to run applications on the user's machine (i.e. client).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use Click Once, it can start via a URL.

Comment: Click Once is the sure fire way to proceed, if you use Visual Studio .Net, its easy to do.  If the user doesn't have the application already installed, it installs into a special area of My Documents, so every user has permission to install the application.   

You can also setup the application, that it only starts, when the user is online, if you need to access the data for the app from a webserver.

So, search about for 'Click Once' deployment.

Comment: My application is currently a VB6 application, but this idea triggered another idea.  Namely, I could create a generic ClickOnce program that will allow me to start up any other program.  I can pass the name of the program and any commandline parameters via the ClickOnce URL.  Kind of round about way of getting there, but it should work.

Answer (score 1):

You're asking about how to do this on the client? I don't think there's any way to start a program using JavaScript.

The best (worst?) you could do would be to use an ActiveX control. Otherwise, you should look into SilverLight.

Comment: +1 for ActiveX, but would Silverlight really have enough permission to launch an external app? I didn't think so.

Comment: No, I was thinking of replacing the WinForms application with SilverLight.

Comment: I've never done any ActiveX programming.  By using ActiveX, does it mean that the winform application will display within the web browser, or will it open in it's own window (i.e. as if the user started the program from a menu or shortcut)?

Comment: I believe the ActiveX control will have to launch the Windows Forms application. This is one of the reasons ActiveX controls are banned in most companies.

Comment: You may be starting to realize why this is a bad idea.

Answer (score 1):

We were able to accomplish this using a browser plug-in.